# Support design library exception

Tags: android

I'm trying to add navigation drawer to my android application but it continuously throws error about error inflation. I've added the support library as well. The xml files doesn't shows the layout, it just shows a grey background with android.support.drawerlayout written on it. Like it does when it can't find that library. I've tried searching on the internet but couldn't find any results that could help me.

[image: Layout File]

Error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.comsian.safetyalert/com.comsian.safetyalert.HomeActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3175)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3312)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:113)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:71)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2038)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:226)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7189)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:576)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:942)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.comsian.safetyalert-J3HAuRvzmTnad2_jIuQroQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.comsian.safetyalert-J3HAuRvzmTnad2_jIuQroQ==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
```

Caused By:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.comsian.safetyalert/com.comsian.safetyalert.HomeActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout

Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.comsian.safetyalert-J3HAuRvzmTnad2_jIuQroQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.comsian.safetyalert-J3HAuRvzmTnad2_jIuQroQ==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64]]
```

Build.grade(app) file:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.0.0"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment:1.0.0'
    implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui:1.0.0'
    implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

Comment: Don't use androidx and support libraries together

Comment: One possible error can be that you are using the AndoidX lib and calling the drawerLayout from the support library, can you confirm your project is not set to import libraries from the AndroidX.

Comment: I've no idea about androidx. I started my project yesterday and androidx libraries were already in gradle file. How can I confirm my project is not set to import libraries from androidx

Answer (score 0):

if you are using `androidx` then use

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"></androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

once this works also replace below dependencies with `androidx`

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
 implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha08'
```

Comment: I've applied these changes but it still is throwing the same errors